# Jquery DataTable se distorciona la tabla al recargar datos

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

Aqui la tabla HTML

```
<table id="Tickets_Abiertos_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue;">No._Ticket</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue; width:140px;">Fecha_Apertura</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue;">Estado</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue; width:150px;">Tipo</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue; width:150px;">Motivo</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue;">Solucción</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue; width:150px;">Area_Responsable</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue;">Abierto_Por</th>
                                            <th class="text-center" style="background-color:skyblue; width:400px">Notas</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                </table>
```

Asi es como inicializo la tabla

```
//inicializacion de la Tabla
       var oOpen_Case_Table = $('#Tickets_Abiertos_table').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "paging": false,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "info": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "scrollY": "48vh",
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("Get_CALL_DATA_OPEN", "Creacion_Tickets")',
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "retnum", "value": $('#agenciaid').val() });
                $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                    fnCallback(json)
                });
            }
        });
```

Y esta es la funcion que utilizo para recargar los datos

```
function Busca_Tickets_Abiertos() {
            if (oOpen_Case_Table != null) {
                //Cambia dinamicamente la ruta del servidor para que no sea estatico.
                var oSettings = oOpen_Case_Table.fnSettings();
                oSettings.sAjaxSource = '@Url.Action("Get_CALL_DATA_OPEN", "Creacion_Tickets")'

                //Busca datos de la tabla
                oOpen_Case_Table.fnDraw();
                oOpen_Case_Table.fnClearTable();
                oOpen_Case_Table.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                oOpen_Case_Table.fnDraw();
            }

        }
```

Esta es la accion MVC que devuelve los datos.

```
public ActionResult Get_CALL_DATA_OPEN(JQueryDataTableParamModel param, String retnum)
        {


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retnum))
            {
                return null;
            }

            List<DR_CALL_DATA> CALL_DATA = Utilidades.Get_CALL_DATA_OPEN(retnum);


            //Select todos los logs encontrados
            var CALL_DATA_ALL = (from e in CALL_DATA
                           select e).ToList();

            //Fintrando por el parametro de busqueda
            var CALL_DATA_FILTRADO = (from e in CALL_DATA_ALL
                                      where (param.sSearch == null || e.caseID.ToString().ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                                                 || e.dateCallOpen.ToString().ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                                                 || e.callStatus.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                                                 || e.callType.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                                                 || e.callIssue.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                                                 || e.callResolution.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                                                 || e.callNotes.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                                                 || e.callOpenedBy.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                                                 || e.queue.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()))
                                    select e).ToList();

            var result = from CALL_DATA_RESULT in CALL_DATA_FILTRADO.Skip(param.iDisplayStart)//.Take(param.iDisplayLength)
                         select new[] {Convert.ToString(CALL_DATA_RESULT.caseID), CALL_DATA_RESULT.dateCallOpen.ToString(),
                                       CALL_DATA_RESULT.callStatus,CALL_DATA_RESULT.callType, CALL_DATA_RESULT.callIssue,
                                       CALL_DATA_RESULT.callResolution,CALL_DATA_RESULT.queue,CALL_DATA_RESULT.callOpenedBy,
                                       CALL_DATA_RESULT.callNotes};



            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = CALL_DATA_ALL.Count(),
                iTotalDisplayRecords = CALL_DATA_FILTRADO.Count(),
                aaData = result
            },
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Y asi se pone la tabla luego de esto. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar la tabla se distorciona, el scroll Horizontal y vertical desaparecen, si vuelvo a buscar entonces si la tabla se pone bien. Me ayudan por favor.

Answer (score 1):

## Actualización

Observando un poco mas mis códigos anteriores llegue a la propiedad [`fnRowCallback`](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnRowCallback), o bien [`rowCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback), en la cual puedes modificar el diseño o la informacion de la columnas. Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('width', '120px');
    $('td:eq(3)', nRow).attr('width', '150px');
    $('td:eq(4)', nRow).attr('width', '150px');
    $('td:eq(6)', nRow).attr('width', '150px');
    $('td:eq(8)', nRow).attr('width', '400px');
  }
});
```

En esta propiedad puedes modificar el diseño de las columnas,

---

Sucede eso debido a que no encuentra correctamente a que `th` corresponde, ya que usas `server-side` te recomiendo agregar la propiedad [`columns`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns), o bien [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs), a esta propiedad le agregas otra que define el ancho `width` para que se adapte a lo que obtienes en tu datatables.

Actualmente si se define un ancho en el encabezado este no tiende a respetarlo ya que ajusta el ancho de acuerdo a la informacion recibida

```
var oOpen_Case_Table = $('#Tickets_Abiertos_table').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "paging": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "info": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "scrollY": "48vh",
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("Get_CALL_DATA_OPEN", "Creacion_Tickets")',
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "retnum", "value": $('#agenciaid').val() });
        $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
            fnCallback(json)
        });
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'No._Ticket'},
        { data: 'Fecha_Apertura', width: '140px' },
        { data: 'Estado' },
        { data: 'Tipo', width: '150px' },
        { data: 'Motivo', width: '150px' },
        { data: 'Solucción' },
        { data: 'Area_Responsable', width: '150px' },
        { data: 'Abierto_Por' },
        { data: 'Notas', width: '400px' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Esta parte no funciono, por que las columnas no tienen nombre, el controlador envia los datos como lista de string, asi                                                                                                             
select new[], en el Json que recibo no aparecen los nombre de las columnas.

Comment: @ElvinAcevedo he actualizado la respuesta, creo que con esa propiedad debería hacer el cambio del ancho.